# how can we select css locator of the drop down arrow key-

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

[image: SCREENSHOT OF THE PAGE I NEED TO AUTOMATE]

I have 3 drop down lists, they are not select class. so I need to click the down arrow key of each element. The css of these arrow keys are same: 
.Select-arrow( used firepath)

HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off"><div class="form-group"><label for="nickname" class="control-label label__floating control-label">Nickname</label><input name="nickname" value="" id="nickname" class="signup-nickname form-control" type="text"><span class="help-block">Ex. LarrySaint, LSJ, LSSaintJohn, LSJohn</span></div><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label label__floating">Job Title</label><div class="Select Select--single"><div class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-2--value"><div role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="react-select-2--value" aria-activedescendant="react-select-2--value" class="Select-input" tabindex="0" aria-readonly="false" style="border: 0px none; width: 1px; display: inline-block;"></div></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div></div><div class="form-container__phone"><div class="form-container__phone--country"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label label__floating">Country Code</label><div class="Select Select--single is-searchable"><div class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-3--value"><div role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="react-select-3--value" aria-activedescendant="react-select-3--value" class="Select-input" tabindex="0" aria-readonly="false" style="border: 0px none; width: 1px; display: inline-block;"></div></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div></div></div><div class="form-container__phone--number"><div class="form-group"><label for="phoneNumber" class="control-label label__floating control-label">Phone Number</label><input disabled="" name="phoneNumber" value="" id="phoneNumber" class="signup-phonenumber form-control" type="text"><span class="help-block">Ex. 855-434-7339, (510) 299 1234</span></div></div></div><div id="timezone"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label label__floating">Select Timezone</label><div class="Select Select--single is-searchable"><div class="Select-control"><span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-4--value"><div role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="react-select-4--value" aria-activedescendant="react-select-4--value" class="Select-input" tabindex="0" aria-readonly="false" style="border: 0px none; width: 1px; display: inline-block;"></div></span><span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span></div></div></div></div></form>
```

so, I am unable to uniquely identify the css values of each drop down arrows. Please help to identify.

In ff console,

```
$$('.Select-arrow')


Array [ <span.Select-arrow>, <span.Select-arrow>, <span.Select-arrow> ]
```

Can I select any one of these elements by its index? Please help me out.

Attempts:

Tried using these xpaths:

```
${NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_JOB_TITLE_DROPDOWN}    //*[@id='react-select-2--value-item']/input
${NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_JOB_TITLE_DROPDOWN_OPTION4}     //*[@id='react-select-2--option-4']
${NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_COUNTRY_CODE_DROPDOWN}    //*[@id='react-select-3--value-item']/input
${NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_COUNTRY_CODE_DROPDOWN_OPTION96}    //*[@id='react-select-3--option-96']
${NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_TIME_ZONE_DROPDOWN}       //*[@id='react-select-4--value-item']/input
${NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_TIME_ZONE_DROPDOWN_OPTION102}      //*[@id='react-select-4--option-102']
```

These didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both XPath or CSS Selector to find them. In this case, I recommend XPath because it is more flexible and more tolerance.

1st option: Use **XPath** to find the root element of each arrow by text in label element.

```
NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_JOB_TITLE_DROPDOWN: "//label[contains(text(),'Job Title')]/..//span[@class='Select-arrow']"
NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_COUNTRY_CODE_DROPDOWN: "//label[contains(text(),'Country Code')]/..//span[@class='Select-arrow']"
NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_TIME_ZONE_DROPDOWN: "//label[contains(text(),'Select Timezone')]/..//span[@class='Select-arrow']"
```

2nd option: Use **CSS Selector** with specific id, class name, is-searchable, or order.

```
NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_JOB_TITLE_DROPDOWN: "div.Select:not(.is-searchable) span.Select-arrow" //supposing the Job Title dropdown is not searchable.
NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_JOB_TITLE_DROPDOWN: "form > div:nth-child(2) span.Select-arrow" //supposing the Job Title dropdown is always the second item in the form.
NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_COUNTRY_CODE_DROPDOWN: "div[class*='__phone--country'] span.Select-arrow"
NEW_USER_LOGIN_PAGE_TIME_ZONE_DROPDOWN: "#timezone span.Select-arrow"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can select them by index with `driver.findElements` (note the 's'). This returns a List of WebElements found by the locator. You can then iterate through the list as any List. For example:

```
List<WebElement> arrows = driver.findElements(By.className("Select-arrow"));
WebElement jobTitle = arrows.get(0);  
WebElement countryCode = arrows.get(1);
WebElement timezone = arrows.get(2);
```